# Travis CI build [Cocoapod Swift] fails with no 'such module...' error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, travis-ci

I've got a [repository](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift/tree/kontent-rebranding) written in Swift, which is a standard cocoapod workspace (standard format with an example app created with Quick and Nimble tests, without UI tests) which builds (and runs with tests) on my local machine (Xcode 11.2.1, macOS Catalina 10.15.1) smoothly, however Travis CI build fails with error that one of the modules does not exist:

```
/Users/travis/build/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift/Example/KenticoKontentDelivery/KontentModels/Cafe.swift:9:8: no such module 'ObjectMapper'
```

Full Travis CI log [here](https://travis-ci.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift/builds/138499511).

[.podspec](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift/blob/kontent-rebranding/KenticoKontentDelivery.podspec) file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'KenticoKontentDelivery'
  s.version          = '2.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'Swift SDK for Kentico Kontent Delivery'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
  Swift SDK for Kentico Kontent Delivery.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'makma' => 'martinmakarsky@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/kenticokontent'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.source_files = 'KenticoKontentDelivery/Classes/**/*'

  s.dependency 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.2.0'
  s.dependency 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.5.1'
  s.dependency 'Kanna', '~> 4.0.2'
  s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2' }

end
```

[Podfile](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift/blob/kontent-rebranding/Example/Podfile):

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'KenticoKontentDelivery_Example' do
  pod 'KenticoKontentDelivery', :path => '../'
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.6.0'
  pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.5.1'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.2.0'


  target 'KenticoKontentDelivery_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Quick', '~> 2.2.0'
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 7.0'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 3.5.1'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.2.0'
  end
end
```

[.travis.yml](https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-delivery-sdk-swift/blob/kontent-rebranding/.travis.yml):

```
osx_image: xcode11.1
language: objective-c
cache: cocoapods
podfile: Example/Podfile
before_install:
- gem install cocoapods # Since Travis is not always on latest version
- pod repo update
- pod install --project-directory=Example
script:
- set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -enableCodeCoverage YES -workspace Example/KenticoKontentDelivery.xcworkspace -scheme KenticoKontentDelivery-Example -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'name=iPhone 8' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
- pod lib lint
after_success:
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: sh ./scripts/push.sh
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
```

What I tried:

- changed versions of all dependencies
- changed osx_image versions

Comment: Make sure your local environment is clean.  For example, `pod install` will run differently in an existing CocoaPods install than a clean one. Also maybe something different between Xcode 11.1 and 11.2?

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion, I've tried it on vanilla macOS installation. I've also tried to adjust the XCode version as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally adjusted settings to be able to successfully run on Travis CI. I'm not sure which setting affects the result, however, after these changes the build and tests run smoothly.

- downgraded `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to version 11
- set `platform :ios, '11.0'` in `Podfile`
- set `s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'` in `.podspec`
- set `s.swift_versions = '5.0'`
- removed `.swift-version` file